# Linux bash code not executing in while-do loop

Tags: bash

I have a while-do loop in a BASH .sh script that does simple command-line parameter parsing.
When i pass certain parameters, they are parsed without problems ( namely the -w, -s , -d parameters ).
But if i pass any other parameter, looks like the loop does nothing and the script keeps executing the code after the end of the while loop.

Neither the "echo" command prints nothing.
Examples -h, --help , -c , --complete, -e. 
I have even tried with non-recognized parameters such as -a -f etc.

Any help please? The while loop is:

```
while [[ $# -gt 1 ]]
do
key="$1"
src_not_valid=false
dst_not_valid=false
site_not_valid=false
complete_bucket_copy=false
exclude_worker=false

echo key $key

case $key in
    -w|--website)
    SITE="$2"
    shift # past argument
    ;;
    -s|--source)
    SRC_ENV="$2"
    shift # past argument
    ;;
    -d|--dest)
    DST_ENV="$2"
    shift # past argument
    ;;
    -c|--complete)
    echo "Complete bucket copy option ON"
    complete_bucket_copy=true
    ;;
    -e|--exlude-worker)
    echo "Exclude worker option ON"
    exclude_worker=true
    ;;
    -h|--help)
    echo $str_help
    exit
    ;;
    *)
            # unknown option
    echo "$2 option not recognized\r\n$usage"
    exit
    ;;
esac
shift # past argument or value
done
```

UPDATE: i forgot to mention that the all parameters that work accept an argument, for example "script-name.sh -w foo -s bar -d john"
But the parameters that do not work, are without arguments, examples -h or --help

Comment: sorry i added it later, but even that "exit" does not have effect if i pass a parameter different than -w , -s or -d.

Comment: The test you're using is (written in arithmetic syntax): `(( $# > 1 ))` (yes, `-gt` is _greater than_), but you mean `(( $# >= 1 ))`: so use `[[ $# -ge 1 ]]` (`-ge` is _greater than or equal_); or better yet, just use arithmetic context (because that's what you doing: arithmetics): `while (( $# >= 1 )); then`; or even `while (($#)); then`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thank you, it works! I can not add you +1 vote for now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't even enter in the loop when there's only one argument.

You have to change `while [[ $# -gt 1 ]]` by `while [[ $# -ge 1 ]]`

BTW your online help string is empty, which doesn't help the debug too :)